# How to dynamically register multiple beans of the same class in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a spring boot application in which I work with multiple beans of the same class (or interface). Usually I would do it like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private final String id;
  
  public MyClass(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
  
  @Bean
  public MyClass bean1() {
    return new MyClass("some-id");
  }

  @Bean
  public MyClass bean2() {
    return new MyClass("other-id");
  }
}
```

But now I create those beans from json files on the classpath, so I have to create them dynamically. First approach was to simply use a `List<MyClass>` like this:

```
@Bean
public List<MyClass> beans() {
  List<MyClass> instances = createInstancesFromClasspath();
  return instances;
}
```

However this registers the beans under the `List` interface, while creating separate beans registers multiple beans und the `MyClass` class.
This will work when injecting via `@Autowired` but i will cause problems when using

```
applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyClass.class);
```

because I would have to use List.class which is not very helpful because it's too generic.

So next I tried this:

```
@PostConstruct
public registerBeans() {
  List<MyClass> instances = createInstancesFromClasspath();
  for(MyClass instance : instances) {
    applicationContext.registerBean(MyClass.class, () -> instance);
  }
}
```

But this throws an exception as soon as it gets to the second instance. So my question is how can I register a second bean for the same class? It has to be possible because it works when using annotations, so I feel I'm just not using the right method.

Comment: in order to have more than one bean for a single type: use Qualifier. to choose between them you can always implement a Factory pattern

Comment: @Stultuske - while this is true, you can't use it if you want to do it dynamically at runtime.

Comment: The post construct is the wrong place to do this, instead use an `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Finally you shouldn't be adding bean instances but register `BeanDefinition` instances, so that Spring will create the beans for you. You can use the `registerBeanDefinition` method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can try BeanFactoryPostProcessor, Where we can define bean names separately

```
@Component
public class MyClassService implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) 
{

 BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
 
 registry.registerBeanDefinition("MyClass1", BeanDefinitionBuilder
       .genericBeanDefinition(MyClass.class)
       . getBeanDefinition();

 registry.registerBeanDefinition("MyClass2", BeanDefinitionBuilder
       .genericBeanDefinition(MyClass.class)
       . getBeanDefinition();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to do it, but how I've done it up to now is by creating a `MyClassProxy` and creating a bean of that. Something like this:

```
public class MyClassProxy extends MyClass {

  private final List<MyClass> impls;

  public MyClassProxy(List<MyClass> impls) {
    super("proxy-instance");
    this.impls = impls;
  }

  public doSomething() {
     //... pick correct impl and delegate to it.
  }
}
```

Then you can register only one bean (this proxy) and use this where needed.

Implementation details can vary depending on your use case. For example the proxy itself might not extend `MyClass`. It depends.